# C言語で1000000÷65536の整数商と余りを計算，表示するプログラムを本文の条件で作りたいです．

Tags: c

大学で1000000÷65536の整数商と余りを計算，表示するプログラムをC言語で作るという課題が出ました．ただし，除算記号‘/’，モジュロ演算子’%’の使用，各種ライブラリ関数の使用が禁止です．ループ構造も使用禁止，ついでに加算，減算記号．ビットシフト‘<<‘，‘>>‘も禁止．もちろん，あらかじめ計算しておいて，その結果だけ表示するのも禁止です．各種ライブラリ関数の例外として，表示用のprintf関数は使用できます．回答よろしくお願いいたします．

**実行例:**

```
> ./a.out
1000000/65536=15...16960
```

Comment: 実際にプログラムを書くにあたって何がわからないか、困っているのかを説明してください。今のままだと「代わりに課題のプログラムを書いて下さい」といった印象を与えます。

Comment: 説明不足で申し訳ございません．私も数時間考えましたが，割り算を計算するためには，演算記号やループ構造を使用しなければプログラムを書くことができませんでした．つまり，これらを使用せずにプログラムを書く方法を教えていただきたいです．

Comment: そこまで使用禁止な物がたくさん列挙されていると逆に「何を使えと言われているのか」を推測できそうにも思えますね．（bit-wise な演算くらいしか残ってない感）

Comment: 質問の条件をクリアした方法でも色々やり方あるだろうけど、そこまでガチガチに条件縛ってるなら、授業の内容と関係していて、それに沿った解き方を求められてるんじゃないですかね。というか、課題は自分でやりましょう。

Answer (score 1):

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  int a = 1000000 & ~65535;
  short *b = (short *)&a;
  printf("1000000/65536=%d...%d\n", b[0] ? b[0] : b[1], 1000000 & 65535);
}
```

Comment: コメントありがとうございます．無事実行することができました．ですが，一部のコードの意味が分からないので，1000000 & ~65535と((short *)&a)[1]の部分をを詳しく説明していただけると幸いです．

Comment: `~65535` は 32 ビットの上位 16 ビットが全て `1` , 下位 16 ビットが全て `0` になります。(ビット反転) そして、`1000000 & ~65536` では下位16ビットの部分を全て `0` にします。この上位16ビットが商(quotient)に相当するので、int を short int の配列と見做して上位16ビットの部分だけを取り出しています。(`((short *)&a)[1]`, リトルエンディアン前提で `[1]` としています)

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます．理解できました．

Comment: 今回の前提(`65536` で除算)では、リトルエンディアンの場合は `((short *)&a)[0]` が `0`、ビッグエンディアンの場合は `((short *)&a)[1]` が `0` になります。それを判別する様に変更しました。

Answer (score 1):

まず前提としてプログラミング言語 C には言語仕様上で未規定としている項目がかなりたくさんあります。 コンピュータには様々な設計がありうるため、それらの都合に合わせられるように言語の側で細部を決めていない部分があるのです。

課題の意図はその課題が提示された文脈から読み取らないといけないでしょう。

コンピュータアーキテクチャについての文脈であった場合は (言語仕様として保証していなくても) 対象のコンピュータの特性を利用することを意図しているでしょうし、プログラミング言語の文脈では言語仕様の細部を読む訓練なのかもしれません。

コンピュータの特性に頼る事例は metropolis 氏が提示しており、境界調整やエンディアンについて特性を活用しています。 逆に言えばコンピュータの特性によっては意図した結果になりません。

言語仕様で保証している範囲に厳密 (なつもり) な例を私は考えてみました。

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    long foo = 1000000;

    printf("1000000/65536=%d...%ld\n",
           (foo & 65536 ? 1 : 0) 
           | (foo & 131072 ? 2 : 0) 
           | (foo & 262144 ? 4 : 0) 
           | (foo & 524288 ? 8 : 0) 
           | (foo & 1048576 ? 16 : 0) 
           | (foo & 2097152 ? 32 : 0)
           | (foo & 4194304 ? 64 : 0)
           | (foo & 8388608 ? 128 : 0),
           foo & 65535);
}
```